Как задать цвет текста в стиле для MenuItem при заданном стиле по умолчанию для TextBlock?
Проблема в следующем. Если задан общий стиль для TextBlock, то MenuItem перестаёт реагировать на любые мои попытки поменять цвет текста.
Даже если прям напрямую в атрибуты элемента вписать, реакции никакой не будет
<MenuItem Header="Сохранить" Foreground="Red" Background="Blue" TextBlock.Foreground="Red"/>

При заданном стиле для TextBlock, а точнее если в стиле задать цвет для Foreground, всё, в MenuItem отключается возможность хоть как-то изменить цвет шрифта. При этом Background сменится в примере нормально.
Но если у стиля TextBlock задать ещё и Background, то в меню будет и Background самого MenuItem и свой Background вокруг текста, при этом через атрибут TextBlock не получится сменить Background, т.к. у него его попросту не будет внутри MenuItem.
Для наглядности прилагаю изолированный пример с этой проблемой : https://github.com/spasskiy/WPFMenuItemStyle.git
